# c# UAParser from .NET 3.5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have a function using [UAParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UAParser/3.0.0) library that analyzes User Agents from IIS logs and detects devices type:

```
int tablet = 0;
int pc = 0;
int phone = 0;
var uaParser = Parser.GetDefault();
ClientInfo c = uaParser.Parse(uaString);
string device = getDevices(c);
if (device == "Desktop")
{
  pc ++;
}
else if (device == "Tablet")
{
  tablet++;
}
else if (device == "Mobile")
{
  phone++;

}
else
{
  pc++;
}

 public static string getDevices(ClientInfo c)
    {
        string device = string.Empty;
        switch (c.OS.Family)
        {
            case "Other":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                    device = "Desktop";
                break;
            }
            case "Android":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    if (c.Device.Family == "Generic Smartphone")
                        device = "Mobile";
                    else if (c.Device.Family == "Generic Tablet")
                        device = "Tablet";
                    else if (c.Device.Family.Contains("Lenovo"))
                        device = "Tablet";
                    else 
                        device = "Mobile";
                    }
                break;
            }
            case "iOS":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    if (c.Device.Family == "iPhone")
                        device = "Mobile";
                    else if (c.Device.Family == "iPad")
                        device = "Tablet";

                }
                break;
            }
            case "Linux":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    device = "Desktop";

                }
                break;
            }
            case "Mac OS X":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    device = "Desktop";

                }
                break;
            }
            case "Ubuntu":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    device = "Desktop";

                }
                break;
            }

            case "Windows":
            {
                if (!c.Device.IsSpider)
                {
                    device = "Desktop";

                }
                break;
            }



        }
        return device;

    }
```

I have to use this code on a batch realized previously, using Framework .NET 3.5, but there isn't a version of UAParser compatible for .NET 3.5.  If I change the target framework for my batch, it doesn't compile, because it uses MSUtil library to parse IIS log files that is not compatible for .NET 4.5. Is there a way to do the parsing of user agents in a way that is compatible for .NET 3.5? Thanks

Comment: I'm in the same boat - The UAParser implementation doesn't seem to support this annoyingly